# Get duration between the bot sending the message and user replying

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, chatbot

First of all thank you for your awesome work in building and maintaining this library.
I have a scenario in which I need to check if the person answered within 10 seconds. I have some code that looks similar to this where I measure the start time in the first waterfall step and I measure the end time in the next waterfall step, I ll find the difference between both in the second waterfall step.

```
bot.dialog('/duration', [(session, args)=>{
    session.dialogData.startTime = new Date().getTime()
}, (session, results)=>{
    session.dialogData.endTime = new Date().getTime()
}])
```

I feel that the code above is not accurate. I have seen a session.message.timestamp property. How would it be different than the code above

Is there a better way to measure time differences like these?
How do I account for network latency in such a scenario?
Thank you for your answers in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the time you send the message and then re-evaluate with the message timestamp like:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        session.userData.lastMessageSent = new Date();
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Send something in 10 seconds or you die.');
    },
    function (session, result) {
        if (session.userData.lastMessageSent) {
            var lastMessageSent = new Date(session.userData.lastMessageSent);
            var lastMessageReceived = new Date(session.message.timestamp);

            var diff = lastMessageReceived - lastMessageSent / 1000;

            if (diff >= 10) {
                session.send('Game over.');
            } else  {
                session.send('Good boy!');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: or we can use dialogData since this matters only for the dialog

Comment: Yes, you're right. Maybe it's better to use dialogData.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do that might be using the Application Insights connection when registering a bot.
This way the Bot Framework service measures your requests/responses and stores the timestamp automatically into Application Insights.

Once you [copy the instrumentation key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-create-new-resource) to the bot registration page, events under **customEvents** in [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics).

In case you just to have an actionable code, the answer above is a better solution.

Comment: this is a quiz game and i want a 10 second timeout to answer, what do you think? instrumentation wont be a good idea in my opinion for something like this where 1000s of players are playing questions

Comment: This is done automatically by the bot framework, the code (either c# or node.js) is not involved in the process

Comment: the question is how do I kick the user out of the game if they take more than 10 seconds to reply

Comment: In that case, you're right, but the title for this question is misleading. I'll update the answer accordingly.